# Predict output sample size from MediaCodec for audio in Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-mediacodec, decoder

Is there any way to get or set output sample size using MediaCodec in NDK?
I am using **AMediaCodec_createDecoderByType** to decode different codec. For some of the codecs its fixed like for mp3 it gives 1152, for aac 1024, so on but in case of .wav i am getting different sample size for different device. it varies from 4096 to 16384 (uncertain).
Since I am maintaining a ring buffer blocks post resampling, and playing from that buffer, I want to know at least the maximum sample size initially to allocate same size accordingly. If there is any api or tricks to know it, would be much helpful.
Thanks,